# Player object has only few functions

Tags: youtube-api

When I retrieve a player object from `event.target` upon `playerStateChange`, it lacks essential functions; it has functions `addEventListener, destroy, getIframe, getOption, getOptions, getVideoEmbedCode`, but it does not have other functions like playVIdeo() or stopVideo(). As a workaround I store the player object in a jQuery data, but I wonder why I cant retrieve a complete player object from `event.target`. Does anyone have an idea?

This has been also posted on Google Youtube API Forum: [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5675&q=label%3aAPI-YouTube%20event.target&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

Comment: What you're asking for should already be working ... see this jsfiddle for confirmation that event.target does represent a full player upon state Change: http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/QPzY2/ -- maybe if you posted your code we could see some minor bug preventing it from working?

Comment: example site: https://togetherjs.com/examples/youtube/
code: https://github.com/mozilla/togetherjs/blob/develop/togetherjs/youtubeVideos.js
Try loading a different video from the example site to see that `event.target` returns a player object that doesn't have all the functions.